# How to show edittext, listview and positive and negative button in dialogbox?

Tags: android, button, dialog, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

How to show edittext and listview and positive and negative button in dialogbox? I tried to show them separatly but i want all of these in one dialogbox.

To show edit text i tried:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setView(modeList);
builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        String myTextString = savedText.getText().toString().trim();
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry , waht's the problem ceate a XMl having all and inflate that xml and set in setView...?

Comment: @ Dheeresh Singh How to set please give any short example. Thanks.

Comment: did you try `builder.show()`?

Comment: do some google and try to find it.

Comment: [See this Tuts](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-custom-dialog-tutorial.html)

Comment: http://mgmblog.com/2011/03/23/inflating-a-view-for-a-alertdialog/

Comment: I have created my own XML. But how to show ListView in dialog?

Comment: Thanks all. For usefull Tuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You require **custom dialog**.

Read the [android document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) regarding this and there is also a sample code.

You can also found [Tutorials here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

Make a new layout file and:

```
public void showYourCustomDialog(){
    this.showDialog(YOUR_CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
}
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    if(id == YOUR_CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID){
        Dialog d = new Dialog();
        d.setContentView(R.id.your_dialog_layout);
        // maybe more things
        return d;
    } else return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

You can too make a new class file and extends Dialog class. Then you can add new uses to your dialog instead the basics that android provides.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String[] p_values = populate_the_list_with_your_content();
ListView mListview = new ListView(this);    // pass your context here
adpter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.your_raw_item_with_whatever_you_like, p_values);
mListview.setAdapter(adpter);
AlertDialog mAlertDialog;
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
AlertDialog.Builder mBuider = new AlertDialog.Builder(your_context);
mBuider.setTitle("title");  // optional
mBuider.setPositiveButton("positive", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // do what you got to do - just be positive          
    }
});

mBuider.setNegativeButton("Back",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // negative reaction
    }
});

mBuider.setView(mListview);
mAlertDialog = mBuider.create();
lp.copyFrom(mAlertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
mAlertDialog.show();
```

works for me. nJoy!